# Creating variables with pytesseract

Tags: python-2.7, variables, ocr, tesseract

In my code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

The results I get from [here](https://i.redd.it/kx4h4l74rs301.jpg) (just from the question and answers) are:

```
Which team surrendered
the biggest lead in Super
Bowl history?

Atlanta Falcons

Denver Broncos

Buffalo Bills
```

Is there any way to say that lines 1, 2, and 3 are the question, then line 5 is answer 1, etc.?

Comment: Could you list the results printed currently by your code?

Comment: Well, this code is supposed to work with any picture (and therefore any output), but if I use the picture from [link](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2017-06/28/6/asset/buzzfeed-prod-fastlane-03/sub-buzz-12852-1498644629-3.jpg?crop=409%3A612%3B0%2C0&downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto), it would come out like: JK Rowling, then Harry Potter, etc.

Comment: Please add the exact results printed. You should be able to add it in your code in the question. I want to see it so I can help you split the line.  Likely it will not contain newline characters to split on but we may get lucky.

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if that helps you out. If so feel free to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your data differs between images this should work. If you always have the '?' to split on.

```
image_text=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
text_list=image_text.split('?')
```

This will give you a list with 2 elements. First being all before the ? and second after. Such as:

```
print(text_list)
['Which team surrendered\nthe biggest lead in Super\nBowl history',
'\n\nAtlanta Falcons\n\nDenver Broncos\n\nBuffalo Bills']
```

From here you can define q and a. As the question and answer.

```
q =  text_list[0]
a =  [a for a in text_list[1].split('\n') if a]
```

The logic above will keep the new lines for the question leaving it formatted as:

```
Which team surrendered
the biggest lead in Super
Bowl history?
```

Then variable `a` will be filled with a list of the answers without any blank lines in the list. So a `print(a)` would return:

```
['Atlanta Falcons', 'Denver Broncos', 'Buffalo Bills']
```

Keep in mind, this fix is dependent on the text having a `?` in it to define which half of the string is the question vs which is the answer.